# Parsing created_at field JSON twiiter

Tags: php, json, parsing, twitter

How can I get this JSON property in PHP?

```
"created_at":{
  "$date":1381953991000
},
```

Just for your information, this is a piece of twitter date from a json file. I put it in a variable as

```
$tweet = json_decode($tweets);
```

and then I can access all property like this

```
$tweet->text
```

to get the tweet text. But with "created_at" property I can not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

`$tweet->created_at` I used it with Abraham's library and it works perfectly. Obviously remember check with the var that you sent the tweet. I mean:

```
$tweet = $yourvar->post('statuses/update', array("status" => "Something");
var_dump($tweet); // all your tweet data... error, date, tweet ID, etc...
// now you can access via json_decode($tweet)->created_at
```

Comment: I did it as well, if I try to print the content (`echo $tweet->created_at;`), I got:

    Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

My `var_dump($tweet)` for this property is:

["created_at"]=> object(stdClass)#6 (1) { ["$date"]=> int(1381953991000) }

Comment: Use `$tweet->created_at`

Comment: it doesn't work for me. I guess that was because the `$date` property inside of `created_at`.

Any tips?

Comment: ohh, then... $tweet->date-Created_at, are you sure it's called "$date" ??

Comment: It didn't work too. I guess the guy who extracted all this data from twitter, did this for some reason. But I don't know who did. :/
I tried: `$tweet->date-created_at`, `$tweet->date-Created_at`, `$tweet->date->created_at` and so on, but nothing works.

I think that a solution for this is to change all twitter dump. :/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still wondering why PHP cannot interpret `created_at->$date`: You need to put the child node in curly braces with quotes, like `created_at->{'$date'}`